# Lie bracket in the universal enveloping lie algebra of $A_1$

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

> Consider the universal enveloping algebra of $A_1$ with the standard basis $\{e,h,f\}$ where $[h,e]=2e, [h,f]=-2f, [e,f]=h$. I want to show that 
>   $$[e,f^{\otimes n}]=n(n-1)f^{\otimes (n-1)}+n h\otimes f^{\otimes(n-1)}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Here we have defined $f^{\otimes 0}=1, f^{\otimes 1}=f, f^{\otimes 2}=f\otimes f, f^{\otimes 3}=f\otimes f\otimes f, ...$ and so on.

My idea is to do this by induction, however I seem to get stuck everytime.

Comment: $[e,f]=h\otimes 1=h$ is true because we have the Lie algebra $A_1$ which has basis $(e, f,h)$ with the usual Lie brackets.

Comment: Why is $h \otimes 1=h$?

Comment: Because universal enveloping algebra is unital with unit $1$.

Comment: If you find yourself asking why $h\otimes 1=h$, the first thing you should do is review what the definition of $\otimes$ and $1$ are in this context.  You haven't stated exactly how they are defined for you (and there are several possible definitions) but this should be true almost immediately from the definitions.  (But, if you want someone to answer this question, you should edit it to include all the relevant definitions!)

Comment: I don't know where you obtained your formula, but it is incorrect.  See my answer below.  Are your $e$, $h$, and $f$ defined differently from mine?  You never defined your notations, so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we have the following Leibniz product rule: $$\begin{align}[a,bc]&=a(bc)-(bc)a=(abc-bac)+(bac-bca)\\&=(ab-ba)\,c+b\,(ac-ca)=[a,b]\,c+b\,[a,c]\end{align}$$
for any $a,b,c\in \mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.  We let $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ with basis $\{e,h,f\}$ such that
$$[e,f]=h\,,\,\,[h,e]=+2\,e\,,\text{ and }[h,f]=-2\,f\,.$$
Note that
$$\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})=\text{span}\big\{e^ph^qf^r\,\big|\,p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\big\}\,.$$

From the Leibniz rule, we obtain
$$[e,f^n]=[e,f^{n-1}]\,f+f\,[e,f^{n-1}]$$
for every integer $n\geq 1$.  We can induct on $n$ to obtain the following binomial formula
$$[e,f^n]=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\,\binom{n-1}{r} \,f^rhf^{n-1-r}$$
for all positive integers $n$.  However, if we want to write $[e,f^n]$ in the basis $\big\{e^ph^qf^r\,\big|\,p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\big\}$ of $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$, we need to use the equality
$$fh=hf-[h,f]=hf-(-2f)=hf+2f\,.$$
Then, induction on $n$ yields
$$[e,f^n]=2^{n-1}\,hf^{n-1}+2^{n-1}(n-1)\,f^{n-1}\,.$$
This is different from the OP's assertion.

Similarly,
$$[e^m,f]=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}\,\binom{m-1}{r}\,e^rhe^{m-1-r}=2^{m-1}\,e^{m-1}h-2^{m-1}(m-1)\,e^{m-1}$$
for every positive integer $m$.  I wonder what $[e^m,f^n]$ looks like for arbitrary  positive integers $m$ and $n$.  For example,
$$[e^2,f^2]=4ehf+8ef-2h^2-2h\,.$$
This looks to be quite a challenge.

**Remark.**  It is not recommended to use $\otimes$ as the multiplication in $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.  When you write $a\otimes b$, people may interpret this as an element of $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})\otimes \mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.